# How to unchange full screen in html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a picture that should be at 100% of the pc screen, but when I use `100vh` the elements start to adapt and the elements roll off.

Using `height: 100%` makes the image too big and doesn't look like it was originally.

Is it possible to somehow get the value `100vh` once, and then it would be unchanged?

```css
.main_page {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_page">

        <!-- Black wallpaper-->
        <div class="black_opacity">

            <!-- Main wallpaper -->
            <div class="main_wallpaper">
                <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/797132503546069002/1045624974016262234/2801907.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        <!-- Main wallpaper end -->

        </div>

        <!-- Black wallpaper end-->

        <!-- Book-->
        <div class="book_cover">
            <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/797132503546069002/1046492404011782164/20221127_144830.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="book_info">
            <h1> name... </h1>
            <h2> description...</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="button_div">
            <button class="book_buttons" id="Buy"> buy at 2.50$</button>
            <button class="book_buttons" onclick="read_click()"> Read book</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried to use javascript, but I didn't get any response from html.  It didn't take a screen value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the class name in HTML is written as `main_wallpaper` but in CSS it's `.main_page` so you need to rename one of them so they match.  There are a few ways you can achieve full height and screen.  I like one of [CSS-Tricks version](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) of how to do this.

In the HTML:

```
<div class="main_wallpaper">
    <img class="main_img" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/797132503546069002/1045624974016262234/2801907.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

In CSS:

```
.main_wallpaper {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
.main_img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```